# Using parse_datetime from gnu c

Tags: c

I am developing a program for analyzing time series under gnu/linux. To analyze a time window, I want to be able to specify start/end times on the command line. Parsing dates using strptime is simple enough, however I would like to use the flexible 'natural language' format as it is used by the unix ''date'' command. There, this is done using the parse_datetime function.

I have the source of the coreutils, but would like to avoid copying over the code and all attached header files.

My question is: is there a standard library under Unix/Linux which gives access to the full power of `parse_datetime()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you refer to is not part of any standard, nor any stock utility library.  However, it is available as a semi-standalone component as part of [gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/), namely the [parse-datetime module](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/MODULES.html#module=parse-datetime).  You will need to take it and incorporate it into your program; the gnulib distribution has tools for that.  Be aware that if you do this you have to GPL your entire program (this is not a big deal if the program is only for your personal use -- the GPL's requirements only kick in when you start giving the compiled program to other people).

A possible alternative is [`g_date_set_parse`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html#g-date-set-parse) from [GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/), but I can't speak to how clever it is.

Comment: Thanks, Zack. The tools for gnulib an autotools enabled project, so i'll have to add that first.